# I try to recreate a plasma gun from halo into my fps game

Tags: unity

this is my code:

```
public class WeaponTest : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float weaponHeat;
    public float weaponOverHeat = 100f;
    public bool weaponIsOverHeat;    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        //weaponHeat at the start was 0
        weaponHeat = 0;    
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && !weaponIsOverHeat)
        {
            if (weaponHeat < weaponOverHeat)
            {
                Weapon_Shoot();
                weaponHeat = IsHeating();
            }
        }
    }

    float IsHeating()
    {
        weaponHeat += Random.Range(5f, 10f);    
        return weaponHeat;
    }

    void Weapon_Shoot()
    {
        RaycastHit hit;    
        if (Physics.Raycast(playerCam.transform.position, playerCam.transform.forward, out hit, range))
        {
            // code for damaging the enemy
        }
    }    
}
```

the shoot method was function exactly like what is want but I need the cooldown method I already try a few them but it not work exactly like I want. the I idea was went the left mouse was click the weapon heat will increase and when the left mouse was not been click the weapon heat will decrease until it reach 0. I hope you can help me solve this problem

Comment: The shorter the code, the more likely people will read it. I therefore removed some code from your snippet which I am 99.9% sure is unrelated to the problem (assuming there are no runtime errors in your console, but if there were I am sure you would have told us). This should improve the number and speed of answers you receive.

Comment: Can you tell us more about how your current code is insufficient? What does it do, and how does that behavior differ from how you would like it to behave? Keep in mind that not everyone has played every game in existence, so if you just write "I want it to work like it does in halo", you exclude anyone who could perhaps answer the question but never played halo (like me, for example).

Comment: Your IsHeating() is writing twice to your heatStorage (either write the value in the getter or on the result, but not on both). And your total heat will be quite fast full. All you actually ned for decreasing heat is an else clause on your fire condition that substracts the heat.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to decrease the heat all the time when you are not firing. Clamping the value to not go below 0.

```
void Update() {
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && (weaponHeat < weaponOverHeat)){
        Weapon_Shoot();
        weaponHeat += Random.Range(5f, 10f);
    } else {
        weaponHeat = Mathf.Clamp(weaponHeat - Random.Range(5f, 10f), 0f, weaponOverHeat); 
    } 
}
```

But now the fire rate as well as heat build up and cooldown depends on the framerate. Some people will be able to shoot faster (but also overheat sooner). To make it more uniform, you need to include Time.deltaTime.

```
private float fireRate = 0.25f;
private float lastFired = 0f;
private float cooldownRate = 7.5f
void Update()
{
    lastFired += Time.deltaTime;
    if (Input.GetButton("Fire1")) {
        if (weaponHeat < weaponOverHeat && lastFired >= fireRate){
            Weapon_Shoot();
            weaponHeat += Random.Range(5f, 10f);
            lastFired = 0;
        }
    } else {
            //whoever build this thing spent some time on a consistant cooling system
            weaponHeat = Mathf.Clamp(weaponHeat - cooldownRate * Time.deltaTime, 0f, weaponOverHeat);
    } 
}
```

Now even if you hold down the trigger, your weapon won't fire faster than the fireRate. And your weapon will only cooldown if you don't hold the trigger.

Comment: You might want to multiply the heat loss by `Time.deltaTime`. The time since the last `Update` depends on the current framerate. So when you don't do this, then players with faster computers will have faster weapon cooldown. This code also allows players with higher framerate to fire faster, but that's a different issue for a different question.

Comment: Note that you still have a framerate bias here, because players running at a high framerate will get more frequent rolls from `Random.Range`, driving their results closer to the expected value of -7.5 per second, so their cooldown time is more consistent. Meanwhile, players at lower framerates will get fewer rolls in that same interval, with a higher `deltaTime` weight per roll, and be more prone to outliers, making their cooldown time more variable.

Comment: @DMGregory Another problem is, if fireRate gets bigger, the player can cooldown the weapon by releasing the trigger and use single clicks for fire vs no cooldown when keeping the button pressed. But it's a plasma gun, you simply cannot release the trigger.

Comment: what exactly does having a random heating add to the game? It does add visual interest, but I personally think it could be annoying.

Comment: @Millard the original weapon that the OP tries to recreate had the mechanic and it is part of the question.